# Wrapped text above table column and alongside table row

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am trying to make the following table on a Beamer slide:

[image]

I cannot seem to get multicolumn to work properly. First, to add the text on top I use the following code

```
 \frame[plain]{
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{}    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Column Title} & 
 & a           & b \\ \hline
 c   & entry 1   & entry 2\\ \hline
 d   & entry 3 & entry 4 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}}
```

This code produces an error

`Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr \end{center}}`

but it produces the following table:

[image]

Without the multicolumn of course, I just have the simple table:

[image]

How do I use multicolumn/multirow to get the "Row Title" and "Column Title" text as shown? [I don't need the "Row" and "Title" to be on different lines.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would help you, also, my suggestion for you would be to use the `\begin{table}` environment and `\centering` within them, instead of using a `\begin{center}` environment as it will produce extra vertical white spaces.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{XYZ}
        \label{XYZ}
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Column title}                                \\
            \multirow{3}{*}{Row title} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{a}       & b       \\ \cline{2-4} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{c} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{entry 1} & entry 2 \\ \cline{2-4} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{d} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{entry 3} & entry 4 \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

The double line version below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{XYZ}
        \label{XYZ}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
        & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Column title}                                \\
        \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Row\\  title\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{a}       & b       \\ \cline{2-4} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{c} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{entry 1} & entry 2 \\ \cline{2-4} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{d} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{entry 3} & entry 4 \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which without futher ado will give you

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Raaja G! Do you know of a way to align the "Column title" text more to the right? I want it to straddle the 2nd and 3rd column (it is a common title for those two columns).

Comment: @leastaction Try using `\multicolumn{2}{l}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Column title}\\ `  instead of `& \multicolumn{3}{l}{Column title}                                \\ `, I think that might give you what you want. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? (`makecell` allows for line breaks in cells)`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
        \centering\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{rl|l|l}
           \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Column title} \\[0.5ex]
            & & a & b \\ \cline{2-4}
       \multirowcell{2}{Row\\title} & c & entry 1 & entry 2 \\ \cline{2-4}
            & d & entry 3 & entry 4 \\ \cline{2-4}
        \end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]